# Peaks, plateaus and ledges

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence, integer-sequence

I want to find the peaks, plateaus and ledges of an integer sequence, but all my attempts failed.

**1. Example list**

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1};
```

**2. Visualization of the problem**

```
 plot = 
   {0, 0, 1, Callout[Style[2, Red], "ledge"], 2, 3, Style[4, Red], 4, 
   Callout[Style[5, Red], "plateau"], Style[5, Red], Style[5, Red], 
   4, 3, Style[3, Red], 2, 2, Callout[Style[3, Red], "peak"], 2, 1, 1, 
   Style[2, Red], Style[2, Red], 1};

ListPlot[plot, GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

**3. Expected result**

```
result = {0, 0, 1, {2}, 2, 3, {4}, 4, {5, 5, 5}, 4, {3}, 3, 2, 2, {3}, 2, 1, 1, {2, 2}, 1};
```

Comment: +1 Good question but just to be finnicky:  Shouldn't ledges and straths and plateaus be associated with a line segment rather than a point?  (And thank you to @gwr for me learning a new word:  strath.)

Comment: @JimB Please thank kglr, who learned me before. ;-)

Comment: @kglr Sorry about that.  Thank you for the new word!  I only looked at the timing of one of your answers and gwr's answer.  I have yet learned how to read in my old age.

Comment: The expected result should be `{0, 0, 1, {2}, 2, 3, {4}, 4, {5, 5, 
  5}, 4, 3, {3}, 2, 2, {3}, 2, 1, 1, {2, 2}, 1}`,that is, the intermediate results should be `{5, 5, 
  5}, 4, 3, {3}`,see my answer.

Comment: (+1) I think your question is excellent, @eldo! The answers to your question have taught me a lot.

Comment: Why do you accept an answer as the solution that does not produce the "expected result" (e.g., ledges are single points not ranges and you also asked for a simple list output)?

Comment: Fortunately, we don't have to publish the reasonings (if any) behind our votes and acceptances. But at least I would like to thank you for your excellent answer.

Comment: In the expected result, you've marked the ledge after the `5, 5, 5` plateau incorrectly: you've marked the first `3` in the list of numbers (`... {5, 5, 5}, 4, {3}, 3, ...`), but the graph has the second `3` marked, so that segment of the list should be `... {5, 5, 5}, 4, 3, {3}, ...`

Comment: You are welcome and I enjoyed the problem. But your compliments would have been even more welcome had they come earlier. I noted how you took the time to „nitpick“ on Daniel Huber‘s solution, when you are finally rather permissive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1};
```

Using `SequencePosition` with patterns that identify peaks, valleys and ledges:

***Patterns***

```
peakPattern = {a_, b_ , c_ } /; a < b > c;
plateauPattern = {a_, b_, b_ .., c_ } /; a < b > c;
valleyPattern = {a_, b_ , c_ } /; a > b < c;
strathPattern = {a_, b_, b_ .., c_ } /; a > b < c;
ascendingledgePattern = {a_, b_, b_ .., c_ } /; a < b < c;
descendingledgePattern = {a_, b_, b_ .., c_ } /; c < b < a;

patterns = {peakPattern, plateauPattern, ascendingledgePattern, 
   descendingledgePattern, valleyPattern, strathPattern};
```

***Positions***

```
ClearAll[pvlPositions]
pvlPositions[lst_] := Map[MapApply[Span @@ ({##} + {1, -1}) &]]@
   Map[SequencePosition[lst, #] &] @ patterns;

pvlPositions @ list
```

> ```
> {{17 ;; 17},  
>  {9 ;; 11, 21 ;; 22},   
>  {4 ;; 5, 7 ;; 8},   
>  {13 ;; 14},   
>  {},   
>  {15 ;; 16, 19 ;; 20}}
> ```

***Annotations***

We use the positions identified using `pvlPositions` with [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) to add desired annotations and styling:

```
ClearAll[annotateF]

annotateF[lst_, {pos_, lbl_, lp_, clr_}] := 
  SubsetMap[x |-> MapAt[y |-> Callout[y, lbl], {lp}]@
     Map[z |-> Style[z, clr]]@x, lst, pos];

labels = {"peak", "plateau", "ledge", "ledge", "valley", "strath"};
colors = {Red, Orange, Gray, Gray, Blue, Green};
calloutpositions = {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1};

args = MapThread[Splice @ Thread[{##}] &] @
   {pvlPositions[list], labels, calloutpositions, colors};

lista = Fold[annotateF, list, args]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot[lista, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 900], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
peaksValleysLedges[{{a_ ..}, m : {b_ ..}, {c_ ..}}] := Which[
 Length @ m > 1 && a < b < c, $ascendingLedge @ m, 
 Length @ m > 1 && c < b < a, $descendingLedge @ m, 
 Length @ m == 1 && a < b > c, $peak @ m,
 a < b > c , $plateau @ m, 
 Length @ m == 1 && a > b < c, $valley @ m, 
 a > b < c, $strath @ m, 
 True, Splice @ m]
```

We can use [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) and [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html) to identify and annotate peaks, valleys and ledges:

```
annotatePVL = Append[Splice @ Last @ #] @
   Prepend[Splice @ First @ #] @
   BlockMap[peaksValleysLedges, #, 3, 1] & @
   Split[#] &;
```

***Example:***

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1};


annotatePVL @ list
```

[image]

Replace the expressions `$*` with desired functions to add call-outs and styles:

```
pvaldl = {$peak, $valley, $plateau, $strath, $ascendingLedge, $descendingLedge};

labels = Thread[pvaldl -> 
 {"peak", "valley", "plateau", "strath", "ledge", "ledge"}];

colors = {Red, Blue, Orange, Green, Gray, Cyan};

replacements = MapThread[# -> Function[x, Splice @ 
  MapAt[z |-> Callout[z, # /. labels], 
     Map[y |-> Style[y, #2]]@ x, 
     # /. {$peak | $ascendingLedge | $plateau |$strath -> {1}, _ -> {-1}}]]&] @
 {pvaldl, colors};

annotatePVL[list] /. replacements
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[annotatePVL[list] /. replacements, 
 Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[annotatePVL[-list] /. replacements, 
 Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

[image]

Replace `annotatePVL[list]` in `ListPlot[...]` above with `annotatePVL2[list]`, where

```
annotatePVL2 = BlockMap[peaksValleysLedges, #, 3, 1] & @
  Prepend[{#[[2, 1]]}] @ Append[{#[[-2, 1]]}] @ # & @ Split[#] &;
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a solution which is MMA V12.0 compatible ? Thanks

Comment: @SigisK, I don't have access to MMA V12.0. Is there any specific part of the code above that is triggering error messages or not giving the expected result in V12.0?

Comment: Yes I get  error messages leading to  no plots at all but I  managed eventually to get wirth my MMA V12.0  the same results as you by replacing all your ``Splice`` by ``Sequence`` (had to add a ``Flatten``to  your Annotate functions) and rewriting your    "x |-> body"  by the classical Function[x,body].

Answer (score 4):

The function "SequenceCases" will help here. To not only get the values, but also the positions, we expand the data by the positions:

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,
    2, 1};
d = Transpose[{Range[Length[list]], list}];
```

Now we can apply SequenceCases like:

```
plateaus =  SequenceCases[
  d, {{i_, x_}, {_, x_} .., {j_, x_}} -> {{i, x}, {j, x}}]

{{{9, 5}, {11, 5}}}
```

This means: there is a plateau from position 9 to 11 with value 5. Similar:

```
ledges =  SequenceCases[
  d, {{i_, x_}, {j_, x_}, {_, y_}} /; y > x -> {{i, x}, {j, x}}]

{{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}, {{4, 2}, {5, 2}}, {{7, 4}, {8, 4}}, {{15, 2}, {16, 
   2}}, {{19, 1}, {20, 1}}}

peaks = SequenceCases[
  d, {{_, x1_}, {i_, x2_}, {_, x3_}} /; (x2 > x1 && x2 > x3) -> {i, 
    x2}]

{{17, 3}}
```

Comment: Please try to turn this into the expected result of ` {0, 0, 1, {2}, 2, 3, {4}, 4, {5, 5, 5}, 4, {3}, 3, 2, 2, {3}, 2, 1, 1, {2, 2}, 1};` I can't do it. The problem already starts with `plateaus`: There are two and not only one.

Comment: I only see one plateau consisting of 3 or more points. Further, you can put in a bit of effort yourself to change the output.

Comment: There is a plateau of two points at the right end of the curve. Since you are not able or unwilling to give the expected result and put the blame on me instead: Why don't you delete your "answer"?

Answer (score 4):

- The idea is using the second order`Difference` to calculus the three adjacent items to find the concave points.

```
Clear[list,boole,temp];
list = {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,2, 1};
boole = Join[{False}, Negative@Differences[list, 2], {False}];
temp = MapThread[If[! #2, #1, List[#1]] &, {list, boole}];
result=SequenceReplace[{{x_}, a___, {x_}} /; a == x :> {x, a, x}]@temp
```

> `{0, 0, 1, {2}, 2, 3, {4}, 4, {5, 5,  5}, 4, 3, {3}, 2, 2, {3}, 2, 1, 1, {2, 2}, 1}`

```
ListPlot[Flatten@Map[Style[#, Red] &, result, {2}], 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

- We test another data.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {0, 0, 1, 1.1, 2, 2.2, 2.3, 4, 4.2, 5, 5, 5, 4.4, 3.2, 3, 2.1, 
   2, 2.8, 3, 2.5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2};
boole = Join[{False}, Negative@Differences[list, 2], {False}];
temp = MapThread[If[! #2, #1, List[#1]] &, {list, boole}];
result = 
 SequenceReplace[{{x_}, a___, {x_}} /; a == x :> {x, a, x}]@temp
ListPlot[Flatten@Map[Style[#, Red] &, result, {2}], Joined -> True]
```

> `{0, 0, {1}, 1.1, {2}, {2.2}, 2.3, {4}, 4.2, {5, 5,  5}, {4.4}, 3.2, {3}, 2.1, 2, {2.8}, {3}, 2.5, {2}, 1, 1, {2,  2}, 1, {3}, 2, {3}, 2, {3}, 2, {4}, 2}`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### State Machine Approach

I went about this in a classical fashion, e.g., parsing a list of values. One could see this as a **state machine** and we need to keep track of the states `ascendingQ` (movement so far has been upwards in general) and `levelQ` (currently we are neither ascending nor descending) as shown in the state chart below.

[image: State Chart]

The transitions are almost exclusively triggered by the gradient of ascend which we will store as a list `differences` using `Differences[list]`. We will step through the list of gradients incrementing the counter `i` at the end of each transition-driven action (numbered arcs in the starte chart). The basic actions are given in the list below.

[image: Table of Actions]

Whenever we *mark* an element or a list of candidates for ledges, plateaus or straths, we will store the corresponding elements from the list specified by the index values, i.e., `l[[i]]`.

##### Implementation

The code below is now adapted to mark rising and falling ledges differently and it is rather straight forward to adapt it to whatever one needs.

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,
2, 1};

parseList[l_List] := Module[
  {
    differences = Differences @ l, 
    ledgeCandidates = {}, \
    parsedPoints,
    length = (Length @ l) - 1, 
    ascendingQ = False, 
    levelQ = False, 
    mark,
    labelFunc = Function[{elem, str}, Callout[ Style[ elem, Red], str, CalloutMarker -> "Circle"]]    
  }
  ,(* mark a list of points *)
  mark[arg_List, label_String] := With[
    {indices = Flatten @ arg},
    ledgeCandidates = {};
    Which[
      label == "RisingLedge", 
        {
          labelFunc[l[[First @ indices]], "Ledge"],
          l[[Rest @ indices]]
        },
      label == "FallingLedge",
        {
          l[[Most @ indices]],
         labelFunc[l[[Last @ indices]], "Ledge"]
        },
      True,
        labelFunc[l[[#]], label]& /@ indices
    ]
  ];
  (* mark a single point *)
  mark[arg_Integer, label_String] := labelFunc[l[[arg]], label];
  parsedPoints = Table[
    Which[
      (* levelQ and ascendingQ *)
      differences[[i]] > 0 && levelQ && ascendingQ,
      (
        levelQ = False;
        mark[ledgeCandidates, "RisingLedge"]
      )
      ,
      differences[[i]] < 0 && levelQ && ascendingQ,
      (
        levelQ = False;
        ascendingQ = False;
        mark[ledgeCandidates, "Plateau"]
      )
      ,(* levelQ and ¬ascendingQ *)
      differences[[i]] > 0 && levelQ && ¬ascendingQ,
      (
        levelQ = False;
        ascendingQ = True;
        mark[ledgeCandidates, "Strath"]
      )
      ,
      differences[[i]] < 0 && levelQ && ¬ascendingQ,
      (
        levelQ = False;
        mark[ledgeCandidates, "FallingLedge"]
      )
      ,
      differences[[i]] == 0 && levelQ
      ,
      (
        ledgeCandidates = {ledgeCandidates, {i, i + 1}};
        Nothing
      )
      ,(* ¬levelQ and ascendingQ *)
      differences[[i]] > 0 && ¬levelQ && ascendingQ,
        l[[i]]
      ,
      differences[[i]] < 0 && ¬levelQ && ascendingQ,
      (
        ascendingQ = False;
        mark[i, "Peak"]
      )
      ,(* ¬levelQ and ¬ascendingQ *)
      differences[[i]] > 0 && ¬levelQ && ¬ascendingQ,
      (
        ascendingQ = True;
        mark[i, "Valley"]
      )
      ,
      differences[[i]] < 0 && ¬levelQ && ¬ascendingQ,
        l[[i]]
      ,
      True, (* differences[[i]]==0 && ¬levelQ *)
      (
        levelQ = True;
        ledgeCandidates = {ledgeCandidates, {i, i + 1}};
        Nothing
      )
    ]
    ,
    {i, 1, length}
  ];
  (* Handle last section *) 
  parsedPoints = Flatten @ {
    parsedPoints
    ,
    Which[
      levelQ && ¬ascendingQ, mark[ledgeCandidates, "Strath"]
      ,
      levelQ && ascendingQ, mark[ledgeCandidates, "Plateau"]
      ,
      True, l[[length + 1]]
    ]
  }
]

parseList @ list // ListPlot[ #, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangePadding -> 0.5, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]&
```

[image: ListPlot]

#### Requested List Output

Using pattern matching it is rather straight forward to come up with the requested list form for the output from `parseList`:

```
toListOutput = Function[ arg, arg //RightComposition[
    ReplaceAll[ Callout[val_Integer, ___]| Callout[ Style[ val_Integer,___],___]:> {val}],
    ReplaceRepeated[{a___,Longest[l:Repeated[{val_Integer}]], b___} :> {a, Flatten @ {l}, b}]
  ]
];

parseList @ list // toListOutput
(* {{0,0},1,{2},2,3,{4},4,{5,5,5,5},4,3,{3},{2,2},{3},2,{1,1},{2,2},1} *)
```

#### Performance Comparison

To test performance of different approaches, we will use a bigger list `bigList`. To fairly compare approaches we should compare the time it takes to come up with a result that is ready to be fed to a `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`.

```
SeedRandom["1234"];
bigList = NestList[ # + RandomInteger[{-1, 1}] &, 0, 1000 ];

RepeatedTiming[ parseList @ bigList; ]
(* {0.00395423, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[ annotatePVL @ bigList /. replacements); ]
(* {0.0051159, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[ pvlPositions @ bigList; ]
(* {5.83603, Null} not even ready for plotting *)

(* RepeatedTiming[ ... @ bigList; ] @vindobona's approach *)
(* {0.00395119, Null} *)
```

Comment: Ok, a bit of tweaking (e.g., `Table` to directly produce `parsedPoints` instead of `While` with `i++` and `Reap`/`Sow`, `Flatten` a nested list instead of using `AppendTo`) and the speed (before compilation) is where I thought it should be. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming the adjacent elements differ only by 0 or 1:**

```
list = {0,0,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,4,3,3,2,2,3,2,1,1,2,2,1};

Flatten@MapThread[#1 /@ #2 &, 
   {Join[{Identity}, 
     BlockMap[{Boole[Length@#[[2]] > 1], 
      Sign[Total[-Min@#[[2]] + MinMax[First /@ #]]]} &, Split[#], 3, 1] /. 
        Thread[
         Tuples[{{0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}] -> 
          Map[x |-> Callout[If[x != "", Style[#, Red], #], x] &
            , {"peak", "", "valley",  "plateau", "ledge", "strath"}]]
       , {Identity}]
      , Split[#]} &[list]
   ] // ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large] &
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Nice! A little commentary goes a long way though. ;-)